# Let’s make a huge number with only tiny numbers (pt2)

Tags: mathematics

Using only three 1s and two 2s (i.e. 1,1,1,2,2), can you generate the smallest 3-digit prime number, 101? You can use all mathematical operators you know, such as floor function, factorial, powers/indices*, etc., but concatenation is not allowed (e.g. '11' from 1 and 1 is not permitted).

- Any powers used must be derived from the initial set of three 1s and two 2s - you don't get to use 'squared' (for example) without accounting for the '2' required when writing this as a formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $\large\Bigl(\frac{1}{.1}\Bigr)^2+1^2$

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution, but like an answer in the earlier question it uses a decimal point

> $ 101 = (\frac{1}{.1}) ^ {2} + 2 - 1 $
>
>  $ 101 = 10^2 + 1 $

<strike>Using base 3 without a decimal point</strike>

> $ 101_3 = 10_{10} = 1 + 1 + 2 + (1 + 2)! $

... but $101_3$ isn't a 3-digit prime :(

So going to base 4, without a decimal point

> $ 101_4 = 17_{10} = (1 + 1) ^ {(2 + 2)} + 1 = 2^4 + 1$

Comment: I acknowledge that your answer and mine are virtually the same and that you posted your answer before me.  I promise you that I discovered my answer independently and when I started to type my answer there were no posted answers.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson thank you – we used different ways to dispose of the unneeded $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Only using (1,1,2,2)

> $\left\lceil\sqrt{((2+1)!+1)!\times 2}\,\right\rceil = 101 $

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't count, but it could be easy if

> you use base 3:
> ((1 + 1) / .2) ^ 2 + 1 =
> (2 / .2) ^ 2 + 1 =
> 10 ^ 2 + 1 =
> 100 + 1 =
> 101

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, we can change bases:

> 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 - 1 = 5 == 101 (mod 2)

We can use basic algebra:

> $\frac{1}{.1^2} + 2 - 1 = \frac{1}{.01} + 2 - 1 = 100 + 2 - 1 = 101$

We can also use multifactorials:

> $\frac{(((2+1)!)!!! + 2)}{.2} + 1$ = $\frac{((3!)!!! + 2)}{.2} + 1$ = $\frac{(6!!! + 2)}{.2} + 1$ = $\frac{48 + 2}{.2} + 1$ = $\frac{50}{.2} + 1$ = $100 + 1 = 101$

Or we can use a little bit of everything:

> $[\sum_{n=1}^{((1+2)!)!!!!} (n+2)] - 1 = [\sum_{n=1}^{12} n+2] - 1 = 102 - 1 = 101$

Comment: I like that last solution a lot!